# Recommendation for Layout Manager

Tags: java, swing, alignment, border-layout, gui-design

I am creating a GUI for an arcade game. It consist of a single JFrame with some JPanels and one JMenu as shown in the figure:

[image]

I've been trying using BorderLayout but it doesn't show the panels properly. What I get is that the JMenu shows properly. [1] adjusts its width to content the buttons inside it. The JPanel [2] fulfill almost the rest of the screen. And [3] shows just as a thin line at the end.

Here's the fragment of code that I use to put them in position:

```
    add(new TopMenu(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);    // JMenu
    add(new LeftPanel(), BorderLayout.WEST);        // [1]
    add(new StatusPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);    // [2]
    add(new GameUI(), BorderLayout.LINE_END);       // [3]
```

Any suggestions of what could be provoking this behavior are welcome.

Comment: I guess this is Hovercraft's answer, but nest JPanel_2 and JPanel_3 in a rightPanel.  JPanel_1 would be the leftPanel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always nest JPanels/containers, each using its own layout. So the overall layout could be a BorderLayout with the menu at the BorderLayout.NORTH and the JPanel [1] on the BorderLayout.EAST side, then nest a JPanel into the BorderLayout.CENTER position using either another BorderLayout or a BoxLayout and put your other two JPanels into this JPanel. For instance this CENTER JPanel could use BorderLayout and it could hold JPanel [2] in its BorderLayout.NORTH position and JPanel [3] in its BorderLayout.CENTER position.

Comment: I hope your GUI code isn't as convoluted as your paragraph construction.  :-)

Comment: Thats a solution. Thanks!
But, is there any other Layout Manager that could be more useful in cases like this?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Sorry for that, english isn't my main language. But I'm learning =)

Comment: @al arayaq: There's nothing wrong with nesting JPanels.  You do have to take note of each JPanel's margins.  If the margins become a concern, you can always use the GridBagLayout, where you have more control over the margins.  I learned the GridBagLayout once, and now I just use it for every GUI I build.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I'll have that in mind for the next time 'coz right now I'm a little short of time. Thanks any way.

Comment: tldr; Add another JPanel that contains 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

Your `JPanel`'s have to have Swing components inside, or else they will shrink to the minimum size when you call pack() on the `JFrame`.

Since you're creating a game, you'll need to set the preferred size on your `JPanel`'s, and set the preferred size on the `JFrame`.  I'm assuming you'll want to paint at least one of the `JPanel` components directly using the `paintComponent` method.

You can nest *JPanel-2* and *JPanel-3* in a *rightPanel*.  You can use `FlowLayout` for the *rightPanel* itself, as well as putting *JPanel-1* and *rightPanel* into the `JFrame`.

If you insist on using a layout manager that will lay out the 3 `JPanel`'s without nesting, you will have to use the `GridBagLayout`. *JPanel-1* will be 1 column wide and 2 rows deep.  *JPanel-2* will be 1 column wide and 1 column deep.  *JPanel-3* will be 1 column wide and 1 column deep.

You'll still have to set the preferred size of the 3 `JPanel`'s.